# Prove $A\ \triangle\ B = A^\prime\ \triangle\ B^\prime$, where $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference, and $X^\prime$ is the complement of $X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Help prove that the symmetric difference of the sets is equal to the symmetric difference of the complements of these sets. That is, that 
$$A\ \triangle\ B = A^\prime\ \triangle\ B^\prime$$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `group-theory`?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the powerset with symmetric difference forms a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHS = $A'\Delta B'$

=$(A' \cup B') - (A' \cap B')$    {by definition of symmetric product}

=$(A \cap B)' - (A \cup B)'$   {by de-Morgan's law}

=$(A \cap B)' \cap(A \cup B)$ {$M-N = M\cap N'$ for sets M and N}

=$(A \cup B) - (A \cap B)${Same argument as previous step}

=$A \Delta B$

=LHS

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 1):

$x \in A \Delta B$ iff $x$ is in exactly one of $A$ or $B$. If $x \in A$ it's not in $B$, so in $B'$ and not in $A'$. So it's exactly one of the sets $A'$ or $B'$ as well. Similarly for $x \in B$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the symmetric difference operator $\triangle$ is commutative and associative, then the problem is quite easy.  If you do not know that, then you should try to prove why $\triangle$ is commutative and associative, as it is a very good exercise.  In my prove, I use $X^\complement$ for the complement of a set $X$.

Let $U$ be the universe.  Note that $X^\complement=U\triangle X=X\triangle U$ for any set $X\subseteq U$.  Thus,
$$A^\complement\triangle B^\complement =(A\triangle U)\triangle B^\complement=A\triangle \left(U\triangle B^\complement\right)=A\triangle \left(B^\complement\right)^\complement=A\triangle B\,.$$